# Decoded payload in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm pretty new with JWT in angular 4 so someone help me how i get something like this :

```html
"sub": "1234567890",
 "name": "John Doe",
 "admin": true,
 "iat": 1523038561,
 "exp": 1523042161
```

instead of:

```html
exp: 1523045040, nbf: 1523041440, …}
exp:1523045040
iat:1523041440
jti:"V5YPH8VBeQlQnF2e"
nbf:1523041440
sub:1
```

i use this code to set my token

```html
 Signin(email: string, password:string , type:string): Observable<boolean> {
    
   // console.log(info);
    var data = JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password, type:type });
    return this.http.post(this.server +"user/signin" , data, this.options).map((response: Response) => {
      // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
      let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
      
      if (token) {
          // set token property
          this.token = token;

          // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ email:email , token: token , type: type }));

          // return true to indicate successful login
          return true;
      } else {
          // return false to indicate failed login
          return false;
      }
  });
    }
```

if it not possible how i search the name of user using sub of decoded token

Answer (score 0):

Use the decode method of jwt, ([Check the jwt docs](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)):

```
// get the decoded payload and header
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
const helper = new JwtHelperService();

const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(myRawToken);
```

Comment: i get an error : 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of null

Comment: could you make a stackbliz example?